# Flex AIR - Where is application.xml in IntelliJ

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, intellij-idea

I've created an AIR Desktop project in IntelliJ, and besides src folder, there is only the project iml. In Flash Builder I used to edit application.xml to set application icons for example. Where can I do that in IntelliJ 12? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Project Structure | Modules | [your Flash module] | [your Flash build configuration subnode] | AIR Package tab. There select 'Custom AIR app descriptor template', click 'Create...'. The file will be created.